# Erro no if dentro da modal no php

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código na modal:

```
if ($resultado2 > "")
     foreach ($resultado2 as $grupo2):
       echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td>'.($grupo2->id_valormedicaofauna).'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.($grupo2->nome_filo).'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.($grupo2->nome_classe).'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.($grupo2->nome_subclasse).'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.($grupo2->nome_ordem).'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.($grupo2->nome_familia).'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.($grupo2->nome_genero).'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.($grupo2->nome_especie).'</td>';

       /*aqui rodamos o if para descobrir o score da coleta**/
        if($grupo2->nome_familia == 'Phryganeidae' || 
            $grupo2->nome_familia == 'Odontoceridae' || 
            $grupo2->nome_familia == 'Brachycentridae' ||
            $grupo2->nome_familia == 'Helicopsychidae'||
            $grupo2->nome_familia == 'Gripopterygidae' ||
            $grupo2->nome_familia == 'Leptophlebiidae')
            echo '<td>'."10".'</td>';
        else
            echo '<td>'."0".'</td>';
```

Mas ele não entra no `if`, vai direto pro `else`. Se eu apago o else ele não mostra resultado na tela.

---

tentei destao forma também, mas não obtive sucesso

```
switch ($grupo2->nome_familia){
    case "Odontoceridae":
        echo '<td>'."10".'</td>';
    break;
    case "Phryganeidae":
        echo '<td>'."10".'</td>';
    break;
}
```

Comment: Você tentou printar o $grupo2->nome_familia antes de entrar no if pra ver o quê está retornando? coloca na pergunta de onde está submitando isso também e se possível, insira o código em um CodePen.

Comment: Provavelmente o $grupo2->nome_familia está vindo em branco ou com um nome que não corresponde as opções.

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar chaves nos *if* e *foreach* da seguinte forma:

```
if ($resultado2 > ""){
 foreach ($resultado2 as $grupo2)
 {
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>'.($grupo2->id_valormedicaofauna).'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.($grupo2->nome_filo).'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.($grupo2->nome_classe).'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.($grupo2->nome_subclasse).'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.($grupo2->nome_ordem).'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.($grupo2->nome_familia).'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.($grupo2->nome_genero).'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.($grupo2->nome_especie).'</td>';

   /*aqui rodamos o if para descobrir o score da coleta**/
    if($grupo2->nome_familia == 'Phryganeidae' || 
        $grupo2->nome_familia == 'Odontoceridae' || 
        $grupo2->nome_familia == 'Brachycentridae' ||
        $grupo2->nome_familia == 'Helicopsychidae'||
        $grupo2->nome_familia == 'Gripopterygidae' ||
        $grupo2->nome_familia == 'Leptophlebiidae')
    {
        echo '<td>'."10".'</td>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<td>'."0".'</td>';
    }
  }/*end-foreach*/
}/*end-if*/
```